# Getting the data attribute of dropped object into a sortable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a list of items:

```
<div class='item' data-itemtype="title">Title</div>
```

That I want to drop into a sortable div.

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

I'm using this code:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.item' ).draggable( {
        helper: function ( e ) {
            return $( '<div>' ).addClass( 'block' ).text( $( e.target ).text() );
        },
        connectToSortable: ".content",
        opacity: .8,
    } );
    ///     
    $( '.content' ).sortable( {
        placeholder: 'block-placeholder',
        update: function ( event, ui ) {
            // turn the dragged item into a "block"
            ui.item.addClass( 'block' );
            var itemtype = ui.item.data('itemtype');
            alert( 'this: '+itemtype );
        }
    } );        
    //      
} );
```

Everything works fine but I need to get the data attribute from the item so that I can pass it on to another script. But the result of the data attribute keeps coming up 'undefined'. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome. Try `$(ui.item).data('itemtype')`. Same for the `addClass` line. `$(event.currentTarget).data('itemtype')` might also work. Not too familiar with jQuery UI though.

Comment: Sorry - neither worked. 
    ui.item.addClass( 'block' );
does work however.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you drag the `.item` into the `.content`, the new element inside of `.content` does not contain the `data-itemtype` attribute. To target this attribute, you'll want to refer to the element directly with something like `var itemtype = $('.item').data('itemtype')`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').draggable({
    helper: function(e) {
      return $('<div>').addClass('block').text($(e.target).text());
    },
    connectToSortable: ".content",
    opacity: .8,
  });
  ///     
  $('.content').sortable({
    placeholder: 'block-placeholder',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      // turn the dragged item into a "block"
      ui.item.addClass('block');
      var itemtype = $('.item').data('itemtype');
      alert('this: ' + itemtype);
    }
  });
  //      
});
```

```css
.item, .content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='item' data-itemtype="title">Title</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Alternatively, you'll need to add the attribute to the element as it's copied across, with something like `$(ui.item).attr('data-itemtype', $('.item').data('itemtype'))`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').draggable({
    helper: function(e) {
      return $('<div>').addClass('block').text($(e.target).text());
    },
    connectToSortable: ".content",
    opacity: .8,
  });
  ///     
  $('.content').sortable({
    placeholder: 'block-placeholder',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      // turn the dragged item into a "block"
      ui.item.addClass('block');
      $(ui.item).attr('data-itemtype', $('.item').data('itemtype'));
      var itemtype = ui.item.data('itemtype');
      alert('this: ' + itemtype);
    }
  });
  //      
});
```

```css
.item, .content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='item' data-itemtype="title">Title</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I still run into the problem of targeting the draggable element. If I have three draggables I can't target a particular one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Obsidian - you put me on the right track. Realized I had to re-add the data attribute during the drag and then I could access the data when it dropped.

My solution:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.item' ).draggable( {
        helper: function ( e ) {    
            var itemvar = $(this).data('itemtype');
            return $('<div data-itemtype="'+itemvar+'">').addClass('block').text($(e.target).text());
        },
        connectToSortable: ".content",
        opacity: .8,
    } );
    ///     
    $( '.content' ).sortable( {
        placeholder: 'block-placeholder',
        update: function ( event, ui ) {
            // turn the dragged item into a "block"
            ui.item.addClass( 'block' );
            $(ui.item).attr('data-itemtype', $(this).data('itemtype'));
            var itemtype = ui.item.data('itemtype');
            alert('this: ' + itemtype);
        }
    } );        
    //      
} );
```

Thanks all for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to solve this

#### HTML

```php
@foreach($categories as $data)
  <tr class="sortme">
     <td> {{ $data->category_name }} </td>
     <td> {!! \Str::limit($data->category_description, 50, ' ...')  !!} </td>
     <td> {{ count( $data->products ) }} Product/s</td>
     <td>
       <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{{ route('category.edit', $data->id) }}"> View/Edit </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

#### jQueryUI

```js
$( "tbody" ).sortable({
    items : '.sortme',
    start   : function(event, ui) {
        $(this).attr('data-currentindex', ui.item.index());
    },
    update : function (event, ui) {
        var current_position    = $(this).attr('data-currentindex'),
            category_to_move    = ui.item[0].dataset.category_id,
            desired_position    = ui.item.index();

        console.log( ui.item[0].dataset.category_id );

        $.ajax({
          // my ajax stuff
        })
    }
});
```

Basically I looked through the `ui.item`

Hope this helps someone in the future.